# Is the Simple framework for XML serialization (Simple) implemented as a SAX, Pull or DOM parser?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I am trying to figure out whether or not the [Simple framework for XML serialization (Simple)](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) is implemented as a SAX, Pull or DOM Parser, or something completely different?
Is this what is referred to as a [data binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Data_binding)?
I have tried reading a bunch of places on the projects website, but without luck.
Basically, does anyone know or can anyone read what type of parser is used in the Simple project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a sort of data binding framework, and i'd guess that deserialization is implemented on top of a pull parser.